# Getting "Expected ',' or '{' but found '[selector]'" error

Tags: jquery, input, selector

Getting "Expected ',' or '{' but found '#44559'" error.  My code looks like this:

```
var valueid = $("div#center-box div#empid-textbox input").val(); //valueid=44559
if($("div#esd-names li#" + valueid).length > 0){
   //DO SOMETHING;
};
```

I'm getting the value of what is entered into a textbox input field which in case is "44559"
can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this error.

I call my valueid retrieving function with the following code.  After you press ENTER in a specific textbox the value of the textbox is retrieved and ran against list items to see if it exists...if it does -- //DO SOMETHING//

```
$("div#center-box div#empid-textbox input.id").keypress(function(e){
  key = e.which;
  if(key===13){
    valueid = $("div#center-box div#empid-textbox input").val();
    if($("div#esd-names li[class*='" + valueid + "']").length > 0){
       //DO SOMETHING;
    };
  };
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a number as an id. This is not allowed.

Comment: when I use it as a class instead I get the same error except it says "...but found '0.44559'"

Comment: @sadmicrowave: That'd be because ".44559" is interpreted as a floating-point number with 0 as the integer point. You'll find the same is true in many programming languages.

Comment: but the number is just 44559 (no decimal) -- not .44559 -- for some reason firefox is adding a prefix of 0. to my number all on its own. any recommendations?

Comment: The class selector uses a "." before the class name (i.e. '.class-name').  You're going to need to append a letter or maybe a "_" to the beginning of your number.

Comment: @climbage - I added an "_" to my class-name and this seems to work....can you explain to me why this works though and why I was having a problem in the first place?

Comment: It's as kgiannakakis said -- an id (or class name) starting with a number is not valid and will cause the parser to read it as a number rather than an ident string.

Here's more on variable naming : http://www.codelifter.com/main/tips/tip_020.shtml

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to check? if the list item exists?

***/********* EDITED  **********/***

I tried to recreate it so this is what I have:

HTML:

```
<div id="center-box">
            <div id="empid-textbox">
                <input type="text" class="id" />
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="esd-names">
            <ul>
                <li class="1">John Doe</li>
                <li class="2">Jane Doe</li>
                <li class="4">John Smith</li>
                <li class="8">Jane Smith</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
                $("div#center-box div#empid-textbox input.id").keypress(function(e)
                {
                    key = e.which;
                    if (key === 13)
                    {
                        valueid = $("div#center-box div#empid-textbox input").val();

                        /*this is the only thing I changed*/
                        if ($("div#esd-names li[class*='" + valueid + "']") != null)
                        {
                            //DO SOMETHING;
                            $("div#esd-names li[class*='" + valueid + "']").css("background-color", "red");
                        }
                    }
                });
}
```

And it highlights the correct li every time .. hopefully you can use this .. sorry if I wasn't of any help.

Comment: Yes...I preform an action if it does exist (the DO SOMETHING action in my example).

Comment: you could try either checking if not null:
if($("div#esd-names li#" + valueid) != null)

or checking if id contains your value with:
if($("div#esd-names li[id*=" + valueid + "])

Comment: I just edited the last example .. it's supposed to be [id*= instead of [id8= ... sorry

Comment: I figured this much and did [id*= when i tried it...still no worky

Comment: Actually your syntax is still wrong (missing some quotations you need:......................................   if($("div#esd-names li[id*='" + valueid + "']")....

Comment: can you post some more code, like your html that holds the elements you are trying to access? where do you call your check, on document-ready or ???

Comment: I edited my original question to include more code as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Put the number in a `rel` attribute, and check for that `$("div#esd-names li[rel=" + valueid + "]")`

Comment: When I do that I get a firefox error saying: "Expected identifier or string for the value in attribute selector but found '44559'"